# How to build a form to allow the user to create dynamic attributes in Nuxt/Vue app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to design a form that allows the user to create variants for a product in a Nuxt/Vue app.

- I want to allow user to define the attributes for the variants in a text field. Each variant will then have these attributes and the user can define their values as you can see in the below workflow.
- However, if a user adds a new variant property, that property doesn't show up in the already created variant. I want to add that property in all created variants and obviously in future variants.
- I also want to delete the attributes that have been removed from the variants text field.

How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<template>
<div class="variant-holder mb-4">
   <div
      v-for="(variant, vindex) in form.variants"
      :key="vindex"
      class="variant table-responsive border rounded bg-white shadow-sm position-relative"
      >
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary-light px-2 position-absolute right-0 top-0">
         <b-icon icon="trash" variant="danger"></b-icon>
      </button>
      <b-table-simple borderless class="small">
         <b-tbody>
            <b-tr v-for="(detail, index) in variant.details" :key="index">
               <b-td class="align-middle">
                  <span class="capital">{{ detail.property }}</span>
               </b-td>
               <b-td class="align-middle">
                  <b-form-input v-model.trim="detail.value" size="sm" type="text" required></b-form-input>
               </b-td>
            </b-tr>
         </b-tbody>
      </b-table-simple>
   </div>
</div>

<b-button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary-light btn-block mb-4" @click="addVariantComponent">
   <b-icon icon="plus"></b-icon>
   Add another variant
</b-button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        variant: {
          attributes: [],
        },
        variants: [],
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addVariantComponent() {
      const variant = {
        details: this.variantDetails(),
      }
      this.form.variants.push(variant)
    },
    variantDetails() {
      const details = []
      this.form.variant.attributes.forEach((attribute) => {
        details.push({ property: attribute, value: '' })
      })
      return details
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like using a watcher to deeply watch the `form.variant.attributes` array will be sufficient for you. You'll need to loop over your existing variants and return a new details array for each variant where the values of the details array is based on the new attributes that are supplied to you.

I will warn you, though, that this will cause a reflow for each of the variant details that you modify if you choose to synchronize based on this route. This is not a performance issue until you get to having a hundred or more. If that's never going to be an issue, then this is likely ideal for you.

```
watch: {
  'form.variant.attributes': function (attributes) {
    // map our new variants
    this.form.variants.map((variant) => {
      return {
        // create our new details object from our available attributes
        details: attributes.reduce((carry, attribute) => {
          carry.push(
            // use the existing value or supply a default
            variant.details.find(({ property }) => property === attribute) || {
              property: attribute, 
              value: ''
            }
          )
          return carry
        }, [])
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would separate the two functionality in to two components.

I would create a component called "variant" that gets a prop called "variantsAttributes".

You can watch the prop changes in your variant and get it updated by simply pushing the changes in your local data, thus getting reactive component.

```
  watch: { 
    variantAttributes: function(newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
      console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
    }
  }
```